# collection.build of nested attribute through a remote_link does not create params when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following model:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :clientships, :dependent => :destroy, :after_add => :default_client_info
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clientships, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

In my controller, if I perform the following

```
  def new
    @activity = IndividualActivity.new(params[:activity])
    @activity.clientships.build(:client => Client.first)
    ...
  end
```

and then save the form, it creates the relevant params and submits successfully.

However, if I chose to call the following through a remote link

```
@activity.clientships.build(:client => Client.last)
```

*the view is updated with the new clientship record but when I submit the form, the params[:activity] is not created for the second nested attribute.* ***(Why not!?)***

This is the view:

```
%h1 Create a new Activity

- form_for @activity do |f|
  %div
    = render "activities/client_selector", :f => f

  %div
    = f.submit "Save!"
```

Here is the remote_link's controller action

```
  def add_client

    @activity = IndividualActivity.new(session[:individual_activity])

    # Refresh client
    @activity.clientships.build(:client => Client.find(params[:client_id]))

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

This is the add_client.html.js:

```
page.replace_html "selected_clients", :partial => 'activities/clients'
```

This is the activities/clients partial:

```
- form_for @activity do |f|
  - f.fields_for :clientships do |client_f|
    %tr
      %td= client_f.hidden_field :client_id
      %td= client_f.object.client.full_name
```

**Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this further?** I seem to have come to a dead-end with my debugging... One thing to note, there is a double use of the following form_for used in new.html.haml and the activities/clients partial (is this problematic?)

```
- form_for @activity do |f|
```

I am on rails v2.3.5

Thanks

Comment: You need some view to help you. There are some lack of information

Comment: Added view information. Thanks

Comment: Where does session[:individual_activity] come from and what does it hold?

Comment: The session variable is being updated and saved during the new and create controller methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask about debugging, so the first step may be looking at the server log (log/development.log).

There you should see the "params" hash.
Maybe your params contain "activity"=>{"client_id"=>..} instead of "client_id"=>.. ?

Also look at the generated HTML page - use a Firebug or just use a "view source" method of your browser. Look, especially, for input names.

If everything looks OK, put a few debug calls in your action, and look at the development.log for some database activity - do the SQL queries look like they are doing what you want?

In your question there is no 'save' method. The 'build' method does NOT save the created record. Maybe this is your problem?

```
def add_client
  logger.debug "Creating Activity"
  @activity = IndividualActivity.new(session[:individual_activity])
  logger.debug "Building clientship"
  # Refresh client
  @activity.clientships.build(:client => Client.find(params[:client_id]))
  logger.debug "@activity = #{@activity.inspect}"
  # Maybe you were missing this part of code?
  logger.debug "Saving @activity"
  @activity.save! # use a ! to easily see any problems with saving.
          # Remove in production and add a proper if
  logger.debug "Saved. @activity = #{@activity.inspect}"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

You should create a functional test (in case you haven't already) and ensure that if you send proper parameters, your action works as intended.

The test will narrow your search. If the test fails, you know you have a problem in the action. If the test is OK, you need to ensure the parameters are sent properly, and you probably have the problem in your view.

**UPDATE**:
You said you have TWO forms on the page. This may be the problem, since only one form may be sent at a time. Otherwise it would need to work in a way which can send two requests in one request.

First thing (useful in all similar problems): *validate whether your page has correct HTML structure* - for example http://validator.w3.org would be a good start. Try to make the code validate. I know that some people treat a "green" status as a unachievable mastery, but just it's really not so hard. With valid code you may be sure that the browser really understands what you mean.

Second: Place all your inputs in a single form. You have problems with nested attributes. For start, try to manually insert inputs with name like `<input name="activity[clientship_attributes][0][name]" value="John"/>`, and for existing clientships ensure that there is an input with name = `activity[clientship_attributes][0][id]`.
This is the way nested attributes are handled.

Your view may create such fields automagically. This construction should be what you need: (it worked in one of my old project in rails 2.x, I have just replaced the names with ones you use)

```
<% form_for(@activity) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_field :activity_something %></p>

  <% @activity.clientships.each do |clientship| %>
    <% f.fields_for :clientships, clientship do |cform| %>
      <p><%= cform.text_field :name %></p>
      <p><%= cform.text_fiels :something %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you really want to use a partial there, don't create a new form in the partial. Use only the parts of above code.

To pass a variable to the partial, use :locals attribute in the place where you call render :partial:

```
<%= render :partial => 'clientship', :locals => {:form => f} %>
```

Then, in your partial, you may use a local variable `form` where you would use `f` outside of the partial. You may, of course, map the variables to the same name: `:locals => {:f => f}`

Comment: I can't perform a save for a new_record though...I had already performed all of the necessary debugging steps prior to posting this problem but I haven't yet tried the functional tests. Furthermore, the add_client is creating the correct controls. The troubleshooting required is to address the issue where new a clientship record is created through the add_client controller method but when I submit the form, the params[:activity] is not created for the second nested attribute

Comment: You mean - you try to save, and it does not work? Or you do not want the record to be saved? Are you using the exclamation version of 'save!'? You say: params[:activity] is not created. Does it mean that there should be, but there is no <input name="activity">  on the page? Maybe on your page there are two <form> tags, instead of one?

Comment: params[:activity] should be created but is not. The control <input name="activity"> does appear on the page though! Hmm, my page does have two <form> tags because I do not know how to get my activities/clients partial to create the nested attributes that appear in the main view.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer. 1) use only one form, 2) validate your HTML code, 3) pass variables to partial. I hope this will help.

Comment: Looks promising. I will give this a go and see if it works. Thanks for all of your help.